# SQL with Distinct and Date

Tags: sql, date, distinct

I have the following SQL Statement:

```
select DISTINCT 
    USERID, 
    NAME, 
    SURNAME, 
    RESIDENCE, 
    HIT_DATE 
from PAGE_HIT 
where HIT_DATE < add_months(sysdate, -6);
```

My problem is that I get the records more than once, because `HIT_DATE` is different. For example the result is:

```
editore, editor, eddy, blabla, 28.01.2013

editore, editor, eddy, blabla, 26.01.2013

editore, editor, eddy, blabla, 14.01.2013

editore, editor, eddy, blabla, 03.01.2013
```

But I just want to get the entry with the newest `HIT_DATE`, in this example:

```
editore, editor, eddy, blabla, 28.01.2013
```

I have no idea how I can modify my SQL Statement

Comment: What datatype is HIT_DATE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GROUP BY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html).

```
select
            USERID,
            NAME,
            SURNAME,
            RESIDENCE,
            max(HIT_DATE)
    from
            PAGE_HIT
    where
            HIT_DATE < add_months(sysdate, -6)
    group by
            USERID,
            NAME,
            SURNAME,
            RESIDENCE;
```

Comment: @undefiniert, this is traditionally the part where you vote or accept.

Answer (score 1):

This way :

```
select USERID, NAME, SURNAME, RESIDENCE, max(HIT_DATE) from PAGE_HIT where HIT_DATE < add_months(sysdate, -6)
GROUP BY USERID, NAME, SURNAME, RESIDENCE;
```